# Android - how safe is calling startActivityForResult within onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am designing an app which calls one of a number of child activities based on the return value of a previously called activity.  For example, activity A might lead to B or C, and B might lead to A, B again, or D.

The obvious way is for a child activity to set a value indicating the next child activity to call, which is passed back to the parent, then, in the parent's `onActivityReturn` method, call another child activity with `startActivityForResult` based on that value.  I am assuming that `startActivityForResult` is asynchronous, so the `onActivityReturn` method would, or at least can, continue (and finish) before the child activity returns.

Is this necessarily safe?  What happens if, somehow, the called activity returns before the `onActivityReturn` that called it finishes?

Answer (score 0):

If your flow is controlled by proper conditions, it will not create any issue,
Even for safer side and your flow allow you can create single instance by defining

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also finish(destroy) any **child** before send to **parent**

also you can :

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: I already do that - in fact, isn't calling finish() in the child how the parent's onActivityReturn method gets called?  What I am wondering about is, what effect starting another activity from within onActivityReturn has on the main (parent) activity.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should predict the situation if there are no such apps that can accept your intent, so if there are no such apps your app will crash. Take a look at this example:

```
    // Actions for change cover button
    Button setImageButton = (Button)   rootView.findViewById(R.id.set_image_button);

    setImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

            ComponentName activity = photoPickerIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager());
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

            if (activity != null) {
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "There are no activities for such intent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

So with help of 
        **ComponentName activity = photoPickerIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager());**
you can check that everything is ok.